# Unable To resolve github maven dependency

Tags: java, git, maven, github, github-package-registry

I have successfully hosted a simple maven dependency in GitHub (https://github.com/alapatbh/java-sns-publish/packages/553918). The repository is currently public.

I am now trying to use the dependency in other projects, but I am getting an error `Cannot resolve org.alapatbh:java-sns-publish:1.1-SNAPSHOT`

I have given my credentials in ~.m2/settings.xml as below:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/alapatbh/java-sns-publish</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>alapatbh</username>
      <password>MY_GITHUB_TOKEN</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

And pom.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pull-java-sns</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alapatbh</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-sns-publish</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What is the mistake that I am doing?

#### Edit:

Error from debug :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pull-java-sns: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:pull-java-sns:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
  Failure to find org.alapatbh:java-sns-publish:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
  resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project pull-java-sns: 
  Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:pull-java-sns:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
  Failure to find org.alapatbh:java-sns-publish:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
  resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
```

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -X ...` for debugging and checked `[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): ...` in the output?

Comment: This is the output from Debug :
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2, default, releases+snapshots), github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/alapatbh/java-sns-publish, default, releases+snapshots)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]

I will post the error log in edit.

Comment: "_Failure to find org.alapatbh:java-sns-publish:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT in **https://repo1.maven.org/maven2**_" – the artifact isn't on Maven Central. The link to https://maven.pkg.github.com/alapatbh/java-sns-publish gives _404 page not found_.

Comment: Why is it trying to resolve the dependency from maven central when it is specified as GitHub in settings.xml. What could be the problem?

Comment: IDK, you write "_The repository is currently public._" but I'm getting a 404 for the `pkg` URL. What if you try the snapshot version `1.1-20201228.150548-1` in your POM, which can be downloaded when selecting it under **Assets**.

Comment: @bhanuprakash I don't find any artifacts with snapshot version (jar appending with 1.1-SNAPSHOT). Is jar with version "1.1-20201228.150548-1" is your snapshot version? Any how there is only artifacts(jar) with "1.1-20201228.150548-1" version on your repo so you need to use <version>1.1-20201228.150548-1</version> in your dependency.

Comment: Thanks @sanjay, changing the version number actually resolved the dependency. But wondering why GitHub is proposing a different version while it is creating a different jar.

Comment: Artifacts with `SNAPSHOT` qualifier usually exist in the local Maven repo only. Artifacts in remote repos managed by a repo manager usually have an extended qualifier (e.g. Nexus: „[where the actual number used is composed of a date/timestamp and an enumerator](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/maven-repositories)“) to distinguish artifacts deployed by different people/CI systems at the same moment. So, usually you always declare a `...-SNAPSHOT` version in your POM and the repo manager takes care of sending you the latest. I consider this being a bug in GitHub's repo handling.